# Broken furigana parsing in questions page

Tags: discussion, bug

[This post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/94424/break-down-the-sentence-%E5%96%A7%E5%98%A9%E3%81%91%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8C%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%A4%E3%82%88%E3%81%84%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%86%E3%81%88%E3%81%AB-%E7%94%B7%E5%89%8D%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%81%BE%E3%81%88) has furigana in the title. It renders fine when looking at the post itself, but when you see it in the [questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions#question-summary-94424) page the kana and braces are shown in-line with the main text. I'm sure this didn't used to happen.

I couldn't see anything wrong with the post itself so, unless I'm missing something, I'm assuming a new bug has appeared.

Any chance we can get this fixed please?

**Edit**

19/06/2022 This problem persists.

Comment: Confirmed using up-to-date Firefox v91.11.0 (esr) on Windows 10, as of 2022-07-18.  Still a problem.